# how to slice a 2D plot

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib

I was wondering how I can slice this plot up into smaller strips. [Plot of galaxies positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfghJ.png) I need to make it into slices of a height of 10 and the width needs to remain the same.

This is the code for the plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.figure(figsize=(13,13))
#Don't forget to start from 0 not 1
x=[]
y=[]
z=[]

filename=(r"C:\Users\Melis\OneDrive\Documents\minnimill6.txt")
f1=open(filename)
while 1:
    rawline = f1.readline()
    lines = rawline.strip()
    if lines == '':
        break
    if lines[0] != '#' and lines[0] != 'g':
        line = np.array(list(map(float, lines.split(','))))
        #print (line)
        x.append(line[14])
        y.append(line[15])
        z.append(line[16])

f1.close()

plt.scatter([x],[y])
plt.draw()
```

Comment: `x1 = np.where(np.logical_and(x>0 & x<10))` and the same for `y1 = np.where(np.logical_and(x>0 & x<10))`. Create `x2`,`y2` and so on accordingly. Then `plt.scatter(x1,y1), plt.scatter(x2,y2)` with different colours if you want.

Comment: @ThePredator I ran the code and got this error back: TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'. Would you be able to tell me what this means and possibly how to fix it. Thank you!

Comment: it should be `x1 = x[np.where(np.logical_and(x>0 & x<10))]`, try this

Comment: @ThePredator its still giving me the same error